LMG1210 | EPC2304 High Side Gate Oscillation
I'm using the LMG12010 to drive a half-bridge comprised of two EPC2304s.
I tuned the gate resistors with no supply bus present until both the low and high side gate outputs were to my liking, no overshoot, sharp edges.
The switch node of the half bridge looks wonderful:

But I noticed that once I supplied a (low) bus voltage, while the low side gate waveform looked identical, the high side gate waveform looks... bad:

Maybe 150kHz?
Then I checked the bootstrap capacitor:

...What?
Here is my schematic:

and layout:

I feel like I must be missing something obvious... I have used other half-bridge gate drivers before with far less optimal routing and have never seen the high-side gate signal oscillate like this before!
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

How are you measuring the high side gate voltage (probe and connection?)? What are the mid layers under this section?

I have removed solder mask immediately next to the gate and source of the FETs, and am touching my probe there. The inner layers are faintly visible but the only notable part is there is a copper pour connecting the exposed pad of the LMG1210 to the source of the low side FET. Thanks :)

As of right now, the only thing I can think to do is increase the bootstrap capacitor size. I thought 100n was overkill but looking at some other usages of the LMG1210 with GAN FETs the bootstrap caps are larger, perhaps I have achieved a resonant pair of L and C of this system.

150kHz is soooo slooooww for this oscillation it's freaking me out!

Resolved, just bad probing. Actually, everything works really well! I may increase the boot cap a little bit, but all of the waveforms are really crisp, and everything is operating normally!

Could we know how the probing was at first (what type of probe, lead length, what nodes tip and ground), and how it was resolved?

The original probe was the standard probe that comes with Keysight scopes. I believe it is truly differential, but the ground loop is rather long. When I hooked up my Analog Discovery 2 (which I believe is not truly differential) the waveform looked as expected. Just to make sure, I hooked up the Keysight probe from system ground to high side gate, and the 150kHz was nowhere to be found (but obviously now the signal is biased by the switch node). Another indication that the oscillation had to do with moving the ground of the Keysight probe was that the amplitude increased with the bus voltage.

The user manual: https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/9018-70020/user-manuals/9018-70020.pdf falls short of providing a connection diagram of the ports/cables on the unit, but suffice it to say, given the cautions on pp22-23, it's common-ground. You were probing HS-G and BS to SW, right? There must've been an isolation gap somewhere (perhaps the power supply, then?), and the capacitance of that isolation is what resonated in a loop, through the earth connection, at 150kHz, which drops some voltage across the probe's ground lead and hence introduces error.

Embarrassing, perhaps, but we all have our starting-out or slow-day mistakes. If you'd like to compile these comments into a proper answer, I at least would happily upvote it :)
